# std::pair vs Array

Tags: c++, arrays, std-pair

I am creating a Map with key and value. The values have to have two separate entries.
Now the first two options that come to my mind is
either go with

```
Map< int,array[2] >
```

or

```
Map < int,pair < float,float > >
```

Which one of these two is better when it comes to memory and execution time. I personally think array would be better since we do not need to perform any search functions. I just plan to access the location using subscript and changing them.

Comment: The first one cannot work: arrays aren't copyable or assignable. So you're stuck with the second one.

Comment: `std::array<float, 2>` works in place of the raw array. You could also use a `struct`.

Comment: Assuming you meant `std::array<float,2>`, not that it matters. `-O2 -S` is whats for dinner. Personally I'd hedge a bet a profiler would reveal the time your program spends in the rb-tree search function will dwarf the access time of the element once you have a reference to it. *Measure*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have three choices, and the right one depends on what the two `int` represent.

1. `using mymap = std::map<int, std::array<float, 2>>;`
2. `using mymap = std::map<int, std::pair<float, float>>;`
3. The preferred option for readable code using this construct:

   ```
   struct somethingmeaningful { float meaningful1; float meaningful2; };
   using mymeaningfulmap = std::map<int, somethingmeaninful>;
   ```

Note how the final one magically became meaningful `;-)`.

Also, notice how I completely disregarded your question about which is faster. The reason for this is that *it doesn't matter*. Readable code with *meaningful names* is always more performant in the long run!

Comment: It's also very likely that all three have exactly the same performance, once the compiler has finished with them.

Comment: @Hassan then stop asking questions here about what hypothetically could perform the best and start profiling actual code on actual systems it will be running on.

Comment: @Hassan you might also interrogate your use case  about the `std::map` performance in your scenarios.There might be  better choice if you add values at real time or other better choices if you request values at real time. How about avoiding dynamic allocation?

Answer (score 6):

To get the obvious out of the way, the first example should probably be

```
std::map<int, std::array<float, 2> >
```

But it's not quite clear what you mean by

> [...] plan to access the location using subscript [...]

Note that for a pair, you would do something like

```
std::pair<float, float> a;
a.first = 1.0;
```

while for an array the syntax would look like that

```
std::array<float, 2> a;
a[0] = 1.0;
```

Then an array probably has more overhead, since it provides other functionality like iterators etc. which you won't make use of. The best way is always doing some experimentation. I find that keeping my implementations open for swapping containers and so on also helps me to keep the code clean and modular.

Comment: How does `std::array` have more overhead?

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have said overhead. It's for sure not slower or anything. However, `std::pair` is more light-weight. `std::array` provides convenience functions like `begin`, `end`, `fill` etc. which are in the case of only two elements probably overkill.

Comment: That being said, there is the famous Dijkstra quote: Two or more, use a for ... So `begin` and `end` might be useful after all :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer the initial question:

Compiler is smart enough that both std::pair and an array with 2 elements are exactly the same thing and it will give you the same assembly code. So you will not see any performance difference.

To give you an example:

the following code:

```
#include<utility>
int square(int num) {
    int arr[2] = {0, 1}; 
    std::pair<int, int> p = {0, 1}; 
    return num * num;
}
```

will be converted to:

```
square(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0  // arr[0]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1  // arr[1]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0  // p[0]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 1  // p[1]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        imul    eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

to convert your C/C++ code to assembly you can use this website: https://godbolt.org/